# One release pipeline for all packages of a feed?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is it possible to define just one release pipeline for all the packages of one feed ?

A feed contains artifacts of the same kind (i.e. Debian package). Which means the release process usually is identical. Well, at least, in my case it is. So I'd rather not copy/paste release pipelines for each and every package. But rather define a system wide way of deploying artifacts of one kind.

I've tried to set the trigger's package name to wildcard values. The input is accepted but no release is launched.

The release pipeline looks like this:

[image]

There are various build pipelines making rpm packages. Those publish the rpm files into a feed (e.g. linux_rpm). The release pipeline I'd like to have is waking up for every artifact in the feed. Instead of waking up for one specific package.

Comment: can you share your release and what did you try? to where do you upload the artifacts, to Azure Artifacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to define just one release pipeline for all the
> packages of one feed ?

For this issue, the answer is yes. We can add multiple Azure Artifacts type artifacts. In this way, all packages in a feed can be used as release artifacts.

[image]

Comment: I thought about that one too, but how to distinguish between the artifacts ? It'll download the latest of each one into its own directory. From there, how can I know which artifact I should deploy ?

Comment: We can through `Release.TriggeringArtifact.Alias` [default variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---release) to know the alias of the artifact which triggered the release.

Comment: Great ! I'll have a try and give an update.

Comment: I've been reassigned temporarily on something else. But I can assume this is the way to go. I have been able to programmatically clone and reconfigure a release pipeline. I guess I'll be able to do the same for adding an artifact to an existing pipeline.